# Google +1 callback doesn't fire unless its init/render is delayed

Tags: javascript, callback, google-plus

Take a look at [this jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/opevug/5/).

It contains three Google +1 buttons, all of which should trigger an alert when clicked.

The difference is - the first button is initialized on document.ready, second one inits 200 millis after, and the other is initialized one second after document.ready.

The callbacks for the first button do not function correctly - clicking on it will not trigger an alert.

Is this a known issue? Anything interesting to do other than file a bug report with Google +1? Any other workarounds? If I do work around this by providing a timeout, what's a reasonable value?

I believe this is a regression introduced sometime in the last few weeks.
[Where should this be reported to?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/31286/where-should-i-report-a-bug-relating-to-google-1-button)

**Update**: I [posted this to Google Plus's discussion groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-plus-developers/srBHeCQ88nE).

Comment: They all work for me in Chrome 21

Comment: @Cosmin - consistently? I've reproduced the issue in Firefox and Chrome 21 99% of the time. One time it didn't reproduce. The issue must be related to timing, so it might affected by your geographical location.

Comment: Not aways, but you have error in console after first click : Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL ( it is very long, can't paste it all here ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to report a bug, look at "Report an issue" here:
https://developers.google.com/+/support

I am having trouble reproducing your error. All three buttons trigger alerts.